# How to automatically add 2-way interaction terms in SAS proc hplogistic

Tags: interaction, sas

I am trying to run a model using SAS proc hplogistic.

The syntax I used is (this is just an example, the actual data set has 100 independent variable, so it's difficult to type all interaction terms and quadratic terms manually):

proc hplogistic data = inputdata;
model flag(event = '1') = age gender @2/association;
selection method = stepwise;
run;

where inputdata has 100K rows and 3 columns: flag, age and gender. flag only take value 0 or 1; age has 3 levels: young, middle, old; gender has 2 levels: male and female. I want to automatically add 2-way interaction terms and quadratic terms: age^2, gender^2 and age*gender. @2 is designed for that. However, when I run the code, I got warning message:
NOTE: '@n' notation is only valid with bar effects.

And no interaction terms or quadratic terms returned. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

```
proc hplogistic data = inputdata; 
model flag(event = '1') = age | gender @2 /association; 
selection method = stepwise; 
run;
```

Refer to this [link](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/03/07/collection-effects-pairwise-interactions.html) for more details.